# How can I set my RSS feed time to update feed quicker

Tags: feed

I'm using [WordPress RSS Widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets#Using_RSS_Widgets) for one of my site. But found it's a bit lazy, it's not taking latest updates into the feed.

How can I make it quick in loading new updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress supports external feeds, and parse the feed using a function named [`fetch_feed()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) from [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/). [RSS widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets#Using_RSS_Widgets) is one of them using the same function to fetch external feed.

The Codex says:

> `fetch_feed` caches results for 12 hours by default.

So, the feed you are fetching is actually at least 12 hours old. But a good news is there also that, you can modify the duration of the fetching by using a filter: [`wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime).

How to use that? Simple. Just paste the following code into your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', function(){ return 1800; });
```

Here,
we are using the filter to modify the duration. Here we are passing our new duration with 1800 [seconds]. The calculation is: 30 minutes = 30 min. x 60 sec. = 1800 sec.

Using the simple code you can change the duration.

**Source:**

- [**RSS Widget doesn’t update**](http://www.newtotheweb.net/2009/10/25/rss-widget-doesnt-update) - Internet Builders
- [**Fix the RSS update time on the WordPress RSS widget**](http://www.village-idiot.org/archives/2009/08/04/fix-the-rss-update-time-on-the-wordpress-rss-widget/) - village/idiot.org

Comment: Please do not use `create_function()`. It is very slow and hard to read. Use either real lambdas or regular named functions.

Comment: @toscho: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed it to lambda (it's a new term to me though). Is it correct now? Love to learn more. :)

Comment: Lambda would look like this: `add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', function(){ return 1800; });`.